# boolean valued function in python

Tags: python, function, boolean, boolean-operations

The function (*filteredFastaToYear*) uses another boolean-valued function (*filterHeaderToYear*) which does not work. I would be very grateful for your help:

I have the following task:

I give to my first function (*filteredFastaToYear*) two lists:

```
sequences_inp = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']  
headers_inp = ['2019-9', '2021-2', '2020-1', '2021-5', '2021-8']
```

As output I need only headers from the year 2021 and the belonging sequences:

```
sequences_out = ['DEF', 'JKL', 'MNO']  
headers_out = ['2021', '2021', '2021']
```

I type:

```
sequences_out, headers_out = filteredFastaToYear('2021', sequences_inp, headers_inp)
print(len(sequences_out), len(headers_out))
```

But insted of expected output I get empty lists:

```
output: 0 0
expected output: 3 3
```

Function *filteredFastaToYear*: creates two filtered lists

```
def filteredFastaToYear(year, listOfSequences, listOfHeaders):

    """ output filtered sequence list, header list """
    filtListOfSequences = []
    filtListOfHeaders = []

    """ fasta filtering """
    for i in range(0, len(listOfHeaders)-1):
        if filterHeaderToYear(year, listOfHeaders[i]) == year:
            filtListOfSequences.append(listOfSequences[i])
            filtListOfHeaders.append(listOfHeaders[i])

    return filtListOfSequences, filtListOfHeaders
```

Function *filterHeaderToYear*: choose header from a required year:

```
def filterHeaderToYear(year, listOfHeaders):

    """ split header, find the needed year """
    for header in listOfHeaders:
        header_split = header.split('-')
        if header_split[0] == year:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: If you have an issue with one of the functions, just keep that, and remove everything else. Say what the function gets as input, what the output is, and what is the expected output. That way there won't be any unnecessary info, just the question core

Comment: `filterHeaderToYear` says it takes `listOfHeaders`, but you're passing it `listOfHeaders[i]` -- a single date. Only one of the two functions should be iterating over the full list of headers, not both.

Comment: `ldate_split` is used but nowhere defined. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You could save yourself the bug hunt and do it like this:

```
out = [(s, h[:4]) for s, h in zip(sequences_inp, headers_inp) if h[:4] == '2021']
```

To "unzip" the list of pairs into the two lists you want, use the `zip(* )` trick:

```
s, h = list(zip(*out))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the input year itself in code

```
    for header in listOfHeaders:
        header_split = header.split('-')
```

This will split `2021-19` to `[2,0,2,1,-,1,9]`
Also you have put a check at `if filterHeaderToYear(year, listOfHeaders[i]) == year` which will never excecute as method return `True` or `False` and you are comparing with `year`

Also you are not iterating the full list by doing

```
for i in range(0, len(listOfHeaders) - 1)
```

It will stop one position before the last one.

**Try this code**

```
def filteredFastaToYear(year, listOfSequences, listOfHeaders):
    """ output filtered sequence list, header list """
    filtListOfSequences = []
    filtListOfHeaders = []

    """ fasta filtering """
    for i in range(0, len(listOfHeaders)):
        if filterHeaderToYear(year, listOfHeaders[i]):
            filtListOfSequences.append(listOfSequences[i])
            filtListOfHeaders.append(listOfHeaders[i])

    return filtListOfSequences, filtListOfHeaders

def filterHeaderToYear(year, listOfHeaders):

    """ split header, find the needed year """
    header_split = listOfHeaders.split('-')
    if header_split[0] == year:
        return True

    return False

sequences_inp = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL', 'MNO']
headers_inp = ['2019-9', '2021-2', '2020-1', '2021-5', '2021-8']

sequences_out, headers_out = filteredFastaToYear('2021', sequences_inp, headers_inp)
print(len(sequences_out), len(headers_out)) # 3,3
```